# Since there is no H title on the website consisting of images, is it possible to add H title as display:none?

Tags: seo, technical-seo, heading

I am building a client's website and most of the pages consist of images (in HTML). And I can't change this because my client wants it that way.

Therefore, we don't need to give captions anywhere as the images tell everything and the images have `alt=""` descriptions.

However, some pages do not have a  tag.

If I add a `<h>` tags related to the page to these pages and then apply the `"display: none"` CSS code to these `<h>` tags, will there be a problem?

The reason for doing this is that SEO analysis sites show the lack of a `<h>` tags on the page as a critical problem.

Comment: Lack of text on a page is a critical SEO problem.  Without alt text your client probably wont even rank in image search.

Comment: People find us with our brand name and it is enough for us not to lose our brand name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be more of a problem of hiding headers than having none. This gives me the same feeling as black hat tactics. You would rather not have the signal than fake signals and potentially tanking your ranking.

Why would you think you don't need `alt` attributes? What do you mean the images tell everything?

What if a person can't download the image? What if a person leverages a screen reader and can't see the image? If you are putting images on a page, a must have for all of them is `alt` tags.

You might want to explain to the client the impacts of their decisions and whether they want to change their decisions based on potential impacts.

Comment: In fact, there is a live music page on this page, there are visuals of the artists on which day they appear, more precisely, there are posters.

At the top, there is a general banner related to live music, the user who sees this can understand that it is a live music page and can see the dates and artists by seeing the banners in the images below.